# Installing a light table(editor) in debian

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, editors

I want to install lighttable programming editor in kali Linux(debian).I have downloaded the `tar.gz` version from [here](http://www.lighttable.com).

But I am unable to install the light table .Please help in regarding this.

`./ltbin: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./ltbin)
./ltbin: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: versionGLIBC_2.15' not found (required by ./ltbin)`

Comment: What problem are you having? What have you tried?

Comment: More details please. "unable to install" is severely lacking in information. Please post what you tried and what errors you got.

Comment: Wow, just watched the video for this. This looks really good.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, I think the problem the OP has is that there are no installation instructions at all, therefore he doesn't know where to start.

Comment: @Flup I have tried running LightTable script but it didn't run.

Comment: Ok, if the `LightTable` script didn't run, then you should post the output of that.

Comment: @Graeme Yes there is no installation instruction.

Comment: But the `LightTable` script works for me. If it doesn't for you then you should post the output. Probably you need to install some libraries.

Comment: @Graeme what you have done? I just run ./LightTable and cursor stopped in next line.

Comment: No different from you.

Comment: Can you add the output of `ldd ltbin`?

Comment: ./ltbin: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./ltbin)

Comment: You can find out which version of `libc` you do have with `ls  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so*`. Most likely you have and older version. Unless there is a newer one in the repositories, your best bet will be to compile `LightTable` from source.

Comment: GitHub for `LightTable` is here - https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable

Comment: @Graeme Actually I have already tried some steps to install it from which one step is ln -sf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0 by which my gdm3 stopped working.

Comment: Definitely don't do the above. The run script creates the `libudev` link in the local directory. What you need is a version of `libc` that is compatible with the binary or you need to compile the binary with the one you have.

Comment: How to compile and which binary?

Comment: The `ltbin` binary. There are compilation instructions on the github page.

Comment: @Graeme Thanx..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in node-webkit

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/light-table-discussion/LTAXJKBuxbw

from: https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/972

> The quickest way I found to run LightTable on Debian:
>
> - Copy the download link from LightTable site
> - Paste the link in a browser (or wget) changing the version from 0.6.0 to 0.5.9 (.../bins/0.5.9/LightTableLinux64.tar.gz)
>
> The previous version does not throw the dependency problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue updating libc with the packages of sid (experimental branch).

Here's the link to the thread that explain how to update Debian Wheezy to glib2.15

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863613/how-to-upgrade-glibc-from-version-2-13-to-2-15-on-debian

I'm running Light Table 0.7.2 on debian wheezy with no problems now.